# Git (SourceTree): Repository not Found

Tags: git, version-control, repository, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I use SourceTree to manage my git repositories hosted in visual studio online. I never had problems pushing my changes in the past but out of the blue I suddenly encountered this error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
fatal: repository '[visual-studio-online-repo]' not found
Pushing to [visual-studio-online-repo]

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Original thought it was an intermittent issue but have had no luck the past 2 days. Anyone encountered the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: What does `git branch -avvv` return? Do you see a branch supposed to push to a remote named `visual-studio-online-repo`? What `git remote -v` return?

Comment: @VonC not very familiar with terminal but the first command returned the commits I made locally from the changes. the second command shows 2 origin (fetch and push) with the location of the repo.